# python how do I move my y axis labels to the middle of my horizontal bar graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

this is my code

```
Rate  = ['Total',"10+","20+","30+","40+","50+","60+"]
NetAmount = [4,2,5,-4,8,-6,7][::-1]
df = pd.DataFrame(NetAmount,index=Rate,columns=['Value'])


fig,ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(ax=ax,kind='barh',legend=None,title='Value')
ax.set_ylabel('Rate',fontsize=12)
```

This is my output
[image]

I want labels of my y axis above x=0 not on the extreme left. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could move the left spine and hide the top and right ones:

```
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)

# move back the ylabel to the left (optional)
ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(0, 0.5)
```

output:

[image: matplotlib move yaxis center]

If you want to keep the frame, duplicate the spine:

```
from copy import copy
ax.spines['left_copy'] = copy(ax.spines['left'])
ax.spines['left'].set_position(('data', 0))

ax.yaxis.set_label_coords(0, 0.5)
```

output:

[image: matplotlib moved axis frame remaining]